Finding $2$ positive integers $a$ and $b$ that $(a!+b)(b!+a)$ is exponentiation of 5

How to find all 2 positive integers a, b such that $(a!+b)(b!+a)$ is expotation of $5$

What I tried:
Without loss of generality assume $b ≤ a$ so let $(a!+b) = 5^m$ and $(b!+a) = 5^n$ ($n≤m$ and $m,n ∈ N$) so $$5^m - 5^n = (a! - b!) - (a-b)$ <=> 5^n(5^{m-n}-1) = a!(\frac{a!}{b!}-1) - (a-b)$$ then i couldn't proceed much. Can anyone give hints for this?

It probably helps to notice that if $n\ge5$ then $n!$ is a multiple of $5$.

Also note that $a!$ is a multiple of $b$.

@GerryMyerson If $b≥5$ so both $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of 5. Thank you so much for your help, but unfortunately, I couldn't do anything else.

Since the question only asks for $2$ such positive numbers, you should just try checking some relatively small values. Did you try doing that? Note I found one pair fairly quickly by just starting with the smaller value, say $b$, being $1$.

@JohnOmielan Thank you for your suggestion. I agree that trying small values can be a helpful approach for exploring patterns and gaining insights. However, in this case, the question aims to find all possible pairs of positive integers that satisfy certain conditions, rather than simply finding one or two examples. Therefore, while exploring small values is a good initial step, a more systematic approach is necessary to ensure all possible solutions are identified

You're welcome. However, your question here, both in the title and in the body, asks only about finding a solution of $2$ positive integers. If you want to find all such solutions, please edit your question to make that clear.

Thank you for your response. I appreciate the clarification.

The question asks to find all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ where
$$(a! + b)(b! + a) = 5^{n}, \; n \in \mathbb{N}$$
This means that both $a! + b$ and $b! + a$ must be powers of $5$. Due to the symmetry, WLOG we can do as you did, i.e., consider $b \le a$. Note that there are no solutions where $b \ge 6$. This is because
$$a! + b = b\left(\frac{a!}{b} + 1\right)$$
Since $\frac{a!}{b}$ is the product of all integers from $1$ to $a$, inclusive, except for $b$, and $b \ge 6$, then $5$ must be included. Thus, $5 \mid \frac{a!}{b}$, so $5 \nmid \frac{a!}{b} + 1$, which means $a! + b$ can't be a power of $5$. As such, we only need to check for $1 \le b \le 5$.
Also, note that for $b \lt 5$, we must have $a \lt 5$ as well for $a! + b$ to possibly be a power of $5$. For simpler checking, note that $1! = 1$, $2! = 2$, $3! = 6$, $4! = 24$ and $5! = 120$.
First, for $b = 1$, the only possible value of $a$ is $4$ (since $4! + 1 = 25$ and $1! + 4 = 5$). With $b = 2$, $b = 3$ and $b = 4$, there are no values of $a$ which work. Finally, with $b = 5$, then $a = 5$ works (since $5! + 5 = 125 = 5^3$). Since $b! = 120$, then $a$ must be a multiple of $5$ for $b! + a$ to be a power of $5$. However, with $a \ge 10$, then $a! + b = 5\left(\frac{a!}{5} + 1\right)$ won't be a power of $5$ due to $10$ being a factor of $\frac{a!}{5}$ so $5 \nmid \frac{a!}{5} + 1$. Thus, there are no other solutions.
In summary, the solutions are $(a,b) \in \{(1, 4), (4, 1), (5, 5)\}$.

Intuition:
If $a$ and $b$ are large and roughly equal, then $a!$ and $b!$ would have a lot more factors of $5$ then $a$ and $b$. That means $a! + b$ couldn't be a power of $5$ -- for example if $a!$ is divisible by $125$ and $b$ is only divisible by $25$, then we get $25(5k + \text{something})$ which isn't a power of $5$ since $5k + \text{something}$ is bigger than $1$ and is not divisible by $5$.
Similarly, if $a$ is much bigger then $b$, then $a!$ will have a lot of factors of $5$, and $b$ will have very few, so we have the same problem with $a! + b$.
To make this intuition precise:
how many factors of $5$ are there exactly in $a!$?
There's a formula for this:
$$
\sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{a}{5^k} \right\rfloor.
$$
Ignoring the floor functions and summing the geometric series, that would give us $\frac{a}{4}$, but we need a lower bound. So let's say $5^m \le a < 5^{m+1}$, then we get that the above is
$$
\ge 5^{m-1} + 5^{m-2} + \cdots + 1 = \frac{5^m - 1}{4},
$$
and meanwhile, since $b \le a < 5^{m+1}$ it has at most $m$ factors of $5$.
So, we are done as long as
$$
\frac{5^m - 1}{4} > m \quad\iff\quad 5^m > 4m + 1
$$
which is true for $m \ge 2$. Therefore, $a \ge 25$ is impossible, so $a < 25$.
For the case $5 \le a < 25$ ($m = 1$), the above inequality is $5^m = 5$ and $4m + 1 = 5$, so we must have equality. That means $a!$ must have exactly one factor of $5$ and $b$ must also have exactly one, so $5 \le a < 10$ and $b = 5$.
That leaves us with these two cases, both a finite case check:

$5 \le a \le 9$ and $b = 5$ OR

$a \le 5$ and $b \le a$


Can you finish from here?

First we notice that in order to $(a!+b)(b!+a)$ be a power of 5, both $(a!+b)$ $(b!+a)$ have to be a power of 5, or else the product of both would have a non-five divisor. Let's look at $(a!+b)$. It has to equal to 5, 125, 625... Notice that $5! = 120$, then, if $a=b=5$, $(a!+b) = 120 + 5$, so $(5!+5)(5!+5) = (125)(125) = 15626 = 5^6$.

Good approach, but overlooks $a=1,b=4$
